# Missing commit changes button in Magento connect

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-connect

Recently I have tried to update or install some extensions with Magento 1.9.1.0 this was all working fine. now Im not able to find the `commit changes`, and Im not also able to submit and uninstall or update.

I have tried clear cache and uploaded a new copy of the app folder, js folder.